# ADF Tumbling window trigger - Self Dependency

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created a tumbling window trigger with recurrence as 1 hour and attached it to a pipeline. Whenever the pipeline runs I want to process previous 2 hours after which I want to process current hour.

For Ex: If the pipeline is suppose to process records between 10 AM to 11 AM in that given run I want 8 AM to 10 AM records also to be processed after which I want current window 10 AM to 11 AM to be processed. Similarly when 11 AM to 12 PM window kicks in I want 9 AM to 11 AM to be processed before processing 11 AM to 12 PM.

To achieve this functionality I have created a self dependency with offset as -0.02:00:00 and window size as 0.02:00:00.

But when pipeline is getting triggered it is looking for previous dependency windows (8 AM to 10 AM) from previous runs and only 10 AM to 11 AM records are getting processed.

But my requirement is to even process 8 AM to 10 AM records along with 10 AM to 11 AM in that particular run.

Is the functionality of the self dependency tumbling window limited to check only previous runs but not processing those records? Or am I missing something? How can above scenario be achieved via tumbling window trigger? Is it possible to subtract 2 hours from @trigger().outputs.windowStartTime?

Below is the screenshot of the trigger.

[TumblingWindowWithSelfDependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jv3Xj.png)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

​While adding trigger on your pipeline, you should pass trigger parameters in to pipeline parameters,
your pipeline should have two paramters like startTime and endTime to take values from trigger parameters

System parameters of tumbling window trigger:

`trigger().outputs.windowStartTime` --> 10AM - 2hrs == 8AM// it will process 8AM to 10AM records and the will process records between 10 AM to 11 AM

`trigger().outputs.windowEndTime` ---> 11AM - 2// Here there is no need of going for -2 hrs

startTime --> trigger start time - 2
endTime --> Trigger end time

There is no need of seeting the offset or dependencies.

To achive -2 hours use `addhours()` function: [addHours()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#addhours)